# oracle sql to find min and max using single date column by different row types

Tags: sql, oracle

INPUT :

```
+--------+---------+------+------+------+
| EMP_ID |  DT_1   | ID_1 | ID_2 | ID_3 |
+--------+---------+------+------+------+
|    408 | 4/7/17  |  906 |      |  906 |
|    408 | 4/8/17  |  906 |  799 |  906 |
|    408 | 4/9/17  |  906 |  799 |  906 |
|    408 | 4/10/17 |  906 |  600 |  906 |
|    408 | 4/11/17 |  906 |      |  906 |
|    408 | 4/12/17 |  906 |      |  906 |
|    408 | 4/13/17 |  906 |  799 |  906 |
|    408 | 4/14/17 |  906 |  799 |  906 |
+--------+---------+------+------+------+
```

I need output result as:

```
+--------+---------+---------+------+------+------+
| EMP_ID | FROM_DT |  TO_DT  | ID_1 | ID_2 | ID_3 |
+--------+---------+---------+------+------+------+
|    408 | 4/8/17  | 4/9/17  |  906 |  799 |  906 |
|    408 | 4/10/17 | 4/10/17 |  906 |  600 |  906 |
|    408 | 4/13/17 | 4/14/17 |  906 |  799 |  906 |
+--------+---------+---------+------+------+------+
```

The mismatches (ID1 <> ID2 OR ID1 <> ID3) should have the exact from and to dates leaving the gaps where there are no mismatches.

Comment: check here to see how format table properly https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96125/how-to-format-sql-tables-in-a-stack-overflow-post Just dont use html code, data like that is unreadeable

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Comment: Select the MIN and MAX for all columns and group them by EMP_ID. You'll need to do a JOIN 5x to the same

Comment: Now you need to explain the logic to get that desire output

Comment: Looks like gaps and islands for all rows where id_2 is not null. But that's just guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a variant of gaps-and-islands:

```
select emp_id, id_1, id_2, id_3, min(dt_1), max(dt_1)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by emp_id, id_1, id_2, id_3 order by dt_1) as seqnum
      from t
      where id_2 is not null
     ) t
group by emp_id, id_1, id_2, id_3, (dt_1 - seqnum);
```